# How to fix the error Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks - Interstitial Ads in android?

Tags: android

I've integrated Interstitial Ads in my app. Below are the transition,

```
         - Screen 3 

         - Screen 4 

         - Screen 5 

         - Screen 6 

Screen 2 - Screen 7 

         - Screen 8 

         - Screen 9 

         - Screen 10 

         - Screen 11 

         - Screen 12
```

While the transition happens from Screen 2 to Screen n (Where n is 3-12), an interstitial ad is called. I hope this is allowed to do.

Today, I have received a mail from Admob saying that Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks. How do I fix this? I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Below is the code of one of the activities.

```
public class CC extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {
ConnectivityReceiver conn;

CheckingStatus checkingStatus;

private static final String TAG = "CC";
private AdView mAdView;

InterstitialAd interstitial;

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-4189677300abcdefgh.....";
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checkingStatus=new CheckingStatus();
    conn=new ConnectivityReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(conn, intentFilter);
    checkfunction(CC.this);

    setContentView(R.layout.cc);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CC");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//for banner ads
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        findViewById(R.id.cc1).setOnClickListener(listener_ca);
        findViewById(R.id.cc2).setOnClickListener(listener_cb);
        findViewById(R.id.cc3).setOnClickListener(listener_ccc);


//for interstitial ads
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest aDRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(aDRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }
    });


};

View.OnClickListener listener_ca = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CC.this, pt_ca.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener listener_cb = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CC.this, pt_cb.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener listener_ccc = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CC.this, pt_ccc.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

public void checkfunction(Context context){
    boolean isConnected=ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    checkingStatus.notification(isConnected,context);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    checkfunction(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}
}
```

What changes should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pre-load the ads and on click of the buttons and before the launch of new activity, you need to display them.